# Question about the session in a c# web application

Tags: c#

User LoginUser = new User();
    Session["User"] = LoginUser;

What does it mean to pass an object(LoginUser) to Session? Will the session get any time value from the object(LoginUser)?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "get any time value"? It makes no sense.

Comment: hi i thought the object may give session time out period..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should note that the User object is serialized when you put it in the session of your app.

```
User LoginUser = new User();
```

It has some consequences:
1) the User class must be serializable.

2) When you will access the object later, (see Oded answer), it will be deserialized from the session: You won't keep the same reference.

```
User loginUser = new User();
loginUser.Name="user1";    

Session["User"] = LoginUser;  

loginUser.Name = "user2";

var loginUser2 = (User)Session["User"];  

=> loginUser2.Nam contains "user1";
```

Why does it work this way? When you put an object in the session, the .NET framework will store it somewhere, (perhaps in server memory, in a file or in a DB depending upon the session storage mecanism). To persist your object, it will be *serialized* (transformed into a sequence of bytes). The serialization process is described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx). The serialization process is quite parametrable, and the subject is quite large. Too large to be covered in this post in fact.

To make a serializable class, you can simply add the Serializable attribute to the class, and ensure that all the class fields or properties are serializables too.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
  public string Field{get,set}
}
```

Comment: your answer is fine and i have doubts can you clear it. 1. could you tell me what you mean "serializable and deserializable"... 2. and how/when can i get user2...

Comment: A added some precisions about serialization. To get user2 from the session, you should replace the initial User in your session by the new user (Session["User"] = loginUSer )

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the object to a session variable that will be then accessible throughout the application during that session.

You can then (in other pages, for example) access it like this:

```
User loginUser = (User)Session["User"];
```

You need to be careful when using `loginUser` as if the session times out, or if you have not added the object to the session before hand, it may be `null`.

Comment: Hi Oded as Maupertuis said.. what is the use of this way to get the value at another page/any page.. we can get the value throuh Querystring method also is it?

Comment: @saj - A very complex object will not be easy to represent on the query string (suppose you have 20 properties). Using the session object means you don't need to expose this information in the query string (where anyone can simply change it).